# Multiplying with Empty Edittexts

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, multiplication, is-empty

I have 7 `EditTexts` and I have to multiply each of them together in a formula say a∗b∗c∗d∗e∗f∗g. It is working fine but when one of these `EditTexts` is empty the formula yields nothing. Now the solution is I have to frame seperate cases of each one of them using `if` or `switch` statement. The issue is that there will be 2^7-1=127 such cases or combinations where one of the 7 `EditTexts` is empty within itself or with other edittexts. So what is the shortest way to resolve this?

Comment: What do you expect if one or more `TextEdit`s are empty? The product of the **remaining** numbers, or an error message, because abcdefg = a·b·c·d·e·f·g can not be calculated?

Comment: In the first case, initially fill all 7 `EditText`s with the default value 1 and then always calculate the product of all 7 numbers. In the second case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the number EditText and convert input into numerical values and multiply them together, this will avoid huge number of conditional statements.

```
val editTexts = arrayOf(editText1, editText2, editText3, editText4, editText5, editText6, editText7)
    for (editText in editTexts) {
        val input = editText.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        if (input != null) {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: That does not work. If, for example, exactly the third EditText is empty, the code returns the product of the 6 other numbers, but should return _abcdefg_ or an error message.

Comment: Then we should add any default values for empty fields like this val input = editText.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0 or throws any exception when field is empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem with a single `if` statement:

```
    if (et1.getText().toString().isEmpty() | 
        et2.getText().toString().isEmpty() |
        et3.getText().toString().isEmpty() |
        et4.getText().toString().isEmpty() |
        et5.getText().toString().isEmpty() |
        et6.getText().toString().isEmpty() |
        et7.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
    {
      // Multiplication can not be done
    } else {
      // Do the multiplication
    }
```

Comment: Single if statement..does not work. It is true if somehow all empty edittexts get filled or replaced with number 1, it would work. But I have to give users an option to fill the edittexts with a number of their choice in runtime and then multiply. The problem occurs if one or many of the other edittexts are left empty, the multiplication of remaining non empty edittexts cannot be calculated. There are approximately 7C6...ie 840 combinations that can occur to solve this.....Do something...I did not yet try the solution given by sanjay

Comment: Did you see my two comments below your question? It seems to me that you meant the first version (but then you need to correct your question: You obviously don't want to calculate the formula abcdefg = a·b·c·d·e·f·g - which you can't do at all if an `EditText` is not filled in - but the product of only the **filled in** `EditTexts`). If you fill all 7 `EditTexts` with `android:text="1"` in your layout xml from the beginning, there are no empty `EditTexts` and you can always multiply all 7 numbers. Note: "1" is the default value and can be overwritten by the user.

Comment: Will get back to you clover but dnt think text "1" will work, I need value 1 so when multiplied with say a.b.1 will give ab. Do u hv any idea about val input shared by sanjay or Edit text preference method or using : 0..etc

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: Your problem now is that "1" is a string and not a number? You must always convert **all 7 inputs** into numbers: Multiply the 7 numbers `Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString())` to `Integer.parseInt(editText7.getText().toString())` to get the result. 
Or `Float.parseFloat(editText1.getText().toString())` etc. if you have decimal numbers.